# Runtime Efficiency of colorSpace conversion from BGR

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi3

I was profiling cvtColor (opencv 3.2) for runtime efficiency.
For an image of size 960x960, i got following results (in ms), for converting from BGR colorspace

On PC (corei5 2.4 Ghz)

```
Gray(1.47668)<YUV(2.17967)<HLS(2.78009)<Lab(4.44801)<HSV_Full(5.02791)<Luv(5.27403)<HSV(5.54197)
```

On Raspi 3

```
Gray(6.04175)<Lab(13.3423)<YUV(16.6426)<HSV_Full(19.5293)<HSV(21.5772)<HLS(32.6913)<Luv(63.4961)
```

Two things to know:
1) Why BGR2Luv conversion performace is so much different on PC and Raspi3 ?
2) Can we use LUT to improve the runtime Efficiency for colorSpace conversion ?

Comment: I hope this results are the mean of something like 100 runs, with OpenCV compiled in release with optimizations enabled

Comment: 200 runs. But didn't check for the release with optimization thing. Any quick link on how to do that.

Comment: `cv::getBuildInformation();`, and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32478670/5008845)

Comment: getBuildInformation says Release in Configuration. checkHardwareSupport(CV_CPU_SSE2), useOptimized() both returns true.

Comment: On your Pi also?

Comment: On RasPi, SSE 2 check returns false, else everything is same.

Comment: OK. this was just to be sure that timings were correct... So, not sure about 1), but 2) you can't use a LUT for color space conversion. Sorry, I've not much to add ;)

Comment: Idea behind LUT is, why to waste ticks in re-computation, when we can use fast mapping with LUT, as conversion between values is always same irrespective of image.

Comment: Because you'll have a LUT of 256*256*256 = 16M entries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146257/discussion-between-amit-and-miki).

Comment: The [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Processor) is an ARM CPU. Two different architectures and probably the x86 CPU code is more optimized (SIMD?, Intel IPP?, if used for this function) than the ARM version. Code for the conversion is [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L9291) maybe? On ARM, it is NEON intrinsics that are similar to SSE intrinsics.

Comment: There are some NEON intrinsics [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L6937) for `RGB2Luv_b`.